# Can you draw layers over an AdView? (opnenGL/libgdx)

Tags: android, opengl-es, admob, libgdx

I'm making sort of a drawing program and using admob to get some earnings :)
So what I want is when the user draw a line over the AdView it renders over it and not under. Is it possible or complete crazyness?

Comment: I'm sure it's technically possible with a transparent view on top of the `AdView`, but I think it's also likely it's against the ToS of AdMob to obscure the ad in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is likely against the Admob TOS: http://support.google.com/admob/answer/1307237?hl=en
". Ads should not be placed in areas where users will randomly click or place their fingers on the screen."

...i know as ad advertiser, i would not want anything covering my ads

Comment: hmm, okay I guess I have to give that up, but it would be cool, wouldn't it ;)